# Two way communication between raspberry pi and android over wifi

Tags: android, networking, raspberry-pi, home-automation

I am doing a home automation project on which I control lights and relays connected to a raspberry pi from my phone(Android) using Python over a LAN connection. I have had success in my first version using a flask Webserver(Pi) and requests and kivy on my phone.

However, for my second version I wanted a more two way communication protocol, as at the moment the only way to get data from the pi to the phone is through the response to the request. One of the goal in the second version is to allow more automation and other devices to switch, therefore I want my phone to be notified on state changes. One way of doing it is simply to regularly checking for changes, but I was wondering if I could instead program the pi to notify me on state changes. This would be more akin to a host-host network than Host-Client.
The only way I can think of doing it at the moment is to have a Webserver on my phone and the pi.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `The only way I can think of doing it at the moment is to have a Webserver on my phone and the pi.` It seems you already use one on the pi. And you can use NanoHttpd for Android. Interesting solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be using [MQTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT) instead. It's a lightweight publish-subscribe protocol, designed with small devices in mind.

It also runs on the TCP/IP layer, but when used on devices with power constraints or with bandwidth limitations, it tends to be a better option than a traditional webservice.

You could add as many subscribers as you need to have the two way communication feature.

Here's a basic example of it: https://medium.com/@gaikwadchetan93/android-real-time-communication-using-mqtt-9ea42551475d